# Retrieve category name from a seeded table Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a quick question.
I seeded some category names and I have created a relationship with my post table (Model).
a post belongs to a category and a category can have many posts.. I have also added the foreign id/key, but when I try to retrieve the name of the category, I get an error. The function on my post model is:

```
public function postcategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

...and on my post category model, I have this:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

So when I try to retrieve the category name for a post with this `$post->postcategory->category_name` I get this error:

> Trying to get property 'category_name' of non-object".

What am I doing wrong? I'll appreciate if someone will be kind enough to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: how is your migrations look like?

Comment: Please, provide your migration and also the way you are making the query, because in the error you reported you are referring to `name`, but the error message says `category_name`

Comment: I have changed the text “name” to “category_name”. It was a typo. Does that help with understanding the question?

Comment: What is the name of your category table in the database? Also is the column in the table called category_name?